# Sencha Touch:How to capture Status code Returned by Server

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing a Sencha touch application using SAP 'Odata' proxy.

In my store I am calling the URL for READ operation

http:///sap/opu/odata/sap/TECHHELP/Tickets

I am loading the store manually in the controller using the following code

```
var ticketStore = Ext.getStore("Tickets");
var proxy=ticketStore.getProxy();

ticketStore.load(function(records, operation, success) {

        if(success){

        console.log('loaded records');
        }
        else{
          console.log('loading failed');
        }
    }, this);
```

When the application is executed in browser, in network tab I can see the format

**Status Code:401 Unauthorized**

Now when the URL is executed, I want to capture the exact status Code and the Message in the application.

I want to capture the possible error conditions by checking the status codes returned from server for Eg: 500,401,200,204

How Can I do this?

Regards,

P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was helpful for me.

```
new Ext.data.Store({
model: "Your Model",
proxy:{
type: 'ajax',
url: "SomeURL",
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
type: 'json',
root: 'SOME ROOT'
}),
listeners: {
exception:function (proxy, response,operation) {
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response.responseText); 
}
}
}
})
```

May be this will helpful for you.

Comment: I tried to parse the response.text but it is null, I also tried to read operation.getError() that is an object but I am unable to read the error text.

Comment: Thanks,response.status  gave the right error code. and "response.responseText" gave the response in xml, now when i try to fetch the message out of this response text using code "Ext.decode(response.responseText)" or "JSON.decode(response.responseText)" I get the error **Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code/><message xml:lang="en">Value Tue Sep 03 2013 19:45:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) does not represent a valid date/time</message></error>**

Comment: I need to display the exact error returned by the server **Value Tue Sep 03 2013 19:45:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) does not represent a valid date/time** from the entire response xml

Comment: If you try to parse a xml document use DOMParser. visit http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29307&seqNum=4

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, using the DOMParser I was able to fetch the message.